# RoR Server side function - how to make it?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm using Ruby on rails, backbone. 
My last 2 weeks headace is this for me most important question.
How to make with rails, that my database model would be updated every 1 second with new random values with only server side?
 Lets say: 
ID:1, value1= 55, value2 = 44.     in 1 second rails server somehow does PUT, ID:1, value1: 77, value2 : 32. 
My backbone client-side must only GET these values from database, never PUT. 
So all my users would GET the same values which server calculated once. It would be like 1 PUT/second with server-side function and like 15 GET/second with client side function(if 15 users online).

Could you please post here the code? I cant figure out where to write this server-side function, that it would run only once, not 15 times becouse of 15 users online.. Client side functions i do understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need something like a scheduled jobs, that touches your rails app every n-seconds, it can be achieved using whenever gem or using sidekiq.
Take a look here: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs

Comment: Thanks, checked it out, seems it works like i want it to. At least i can keep working on other things now :)